# Use LWC @wire(getRecord) when recordId is not always present

Tags: lightning-web-components, lwc-wire-adapter

I love how the **LWC Wire Data Service** reduces the amount of boilerplate code.
I have a component which can be placed on Home AND Record pages. On Home pages there is no `recordId` and my call to

```
@wire(getRecord, { recordId: "$recordId", fields: this.fields})
```

fails.

**Is there a way (with minimal extra code) to make it work?**

Comment: What do you want the recordId to be in this case?

Comment: Why is GetRecord needed on home page?

Comment: When a LWC is on a record Page a @api recordId; is populated with the current record id. It stays undefined if the same LWC is on a Home Page.

Comment: @salesforce-sas It is part of a generic component which can go on any page. I just need a way to not make parts of the code fail in such cases

Comment: In that case, you can simply handle undefined in your apex I suppose?

Comment: Yes a simple if(this.recordId){ @wire(getRecord, { recordId: "$recordId", fields: this.fields}) } would work. I would like to know more about your html file. When call fails, what kind of issue you have o screen?

Comment: is  if(this.recordId){ @wire(getRecord, { recordId: "$recordId", fields: this.fields}) } really valid JS?!

Comment: @RobertSösemann are you decorating a property or a method?

Comment: I think the issue might be where the fields of the record that you get from Salesforce is are accessed.  Are you checking for null/undefined at each level of your record object?   

I think I talk about it briefly here https://wipdeveloper.com/lwc-getting-data-with-the-wire-service/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you implement `wire` service, it will always be invoked the first time when its registered while component initialisation. Then it will return `{ data: undefined, error: undefined }`

However it will be invoked again only when dynamic variable `recordId` changes as wire is dependent on it. So, you can safely use `if(this.recordId)` inside the functions which are dependent on record pages context and handle the logic accordingly.