# Get picklist values on record type(not a default) without hard-coding of record type id and object have more than one record type

Tags: lightning-web-components, lightning-combobox

My requirement is to get picklist values from a record type if the object has more than one record type. Some examples are given with default record value passed. But in my requirement record type is not a default record type.

I tried below example but it didn't work. orderTypeOption is not populating with values. 
Use the **recipe app** from a sample gallery in my dev org.

**wireGetPicklistValues.html**

```
<template>
    <lightning-card title="WireGetPicklistValues" icon-name="custom:custom67">
        <div class="slds-m-around_medium" >
              Order type picklist
              <template if:true={orderTypeOption.data}>
                 <lightning-combobox
                    name="progress"
                    label="Order Type"
                    value={orderType}
                    options={orderTypeOption.data.values}
                    ></lightning-combobox>
              </template>
        </div>
        <template if:true={picklistValues.data}>
            <div class="slds-m-around_medium">
                <template for:each={picklistValues.data.values} for:item="item">
                    <lightning-input
                        key={item.value}
                        label={item.label}
                        data-value={item.value}
                        type="checkbox"
                    >
                    </lightning-input>
                </template>
            </div>
        </template>
        <template if:true={picklistValues.error}>
            <c-error-panel errors={picklistValues.error}></c-error-panel>
        </template>

        <c-view-source source="lwc/wireGetPicklistValues" slot="footer">
            Get the picklist values for a specified field. In this example,
            the&nbsp;
            <strong>Type</strong> field of the <strong>Account</strong> object.
        </c-view-source>
    </lightning-card>
</template>
```

**wireGetPicklistValues.js**

```
import { LightningElement, wire, track } from 'lwc';
import { getPicklistValues } from 'lightning/uiObjectInfoApi';
import { getObjectInfo } from 'lightning/uiObjectInfoApi';
import TYPE_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Account.Type';
import ORDERTYPE_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Order.Type';

export default class WireGetPicklistValues extends LightningElement {
    @track orderType;

    @wire(getPicklistValues, {
        recordTypeId: '012000000000000AAA',
        fieldApiName: TYPE_FIELD
    })
    picklistValues;

     @wire(getPicklistValues, {
        recordTypeId: '$recordTypeId',
        fieldApiName: ORDERTYPE_FIELD
    })
    orderTypeOption;

    get recordTypeId() {
        // Returns a map of record type Ids 
        const rtis = this.objectInfo.data.recordTypeInfos;
        return Object.keys(rtis).find(rti => rtis[rti].name === 'Asia');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Added based on comments**

1. The getter `recordTypeId` will not be invoked unless you use it in HTML like `{recordTypeId}` OR by invoking it in JS like `this.recordTypeId()`.
2. `$recordTypeId` is dynamic **PROPERTY** and not a method which will get value from method (getter).
3. You are not setting `objectInfo` anywhere so `recordTypeId()` will never return anything even if used in HTML.

Try below JS:

```
import { LightningElement, wire, api, track } from 'lwc';
import ORDER_OBJECT from '@salesforce/schema/Order';
import { getObjectInfo } from 'lightning/uiObjectInfoApi';
import { getPicklistValues } from 'lightning/uiObjectInfoApi';
import TYPE_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Order.Type';

export default class Poc extends LightningElement {
    @wire(getObjectInfo, { objectApiName: ORDER_OBJECT })
    getobjectInfo(result) {
        if (result.data) {
            const rtis = result.data.recordTypeInfos;
            this.recordTypeId = Object.keys(rtis).find((rti) => rtis[rti].name === 'Asia');
        }
    }

    @wire(getPicklistValues, { recordTypeId: '$recordTypeId', fieldApiName: TYPE_FIELD })
    orderTypeOption;
}
```

---

**previous answer**

In your example I see that you are using `objectInfo` but you are never fetching it.

Pls check below code sample:

```
import { LightningElement, wire, api } from 'lwc';
import ACCOUNT_OBJECT from '@salesforce/schema/Account';
import { getObjectInfo } from 'lightning/uiObjectInfoApi';

export default class Poc extends LightningElement {
    @wire(getObjectInfo, { objectApiName: ACCOUNT_OBJECT })
    getobjectInfo(result) {
        console.log('result => ', JSON.stringify(result.data.recordTypeInfos));
    }
}
```

Here you will get the record types through `result.data.recordTypeInfos`. You will see below data in `recordTypeInfos`.

```
{
  "012000000000000AAA": {
    "available": true,
    "defaultRecordTypeMapping": false,
    "master": true,
    "name": "Master",
    "recordTypeId": "012000000000000AAA"
  },
  "0120K000000TO5FQAW": {
    "available": true,
    "defaultRecordTypeMapping": false,
    "master": false,
    "name": "P1r",
    "recordTypeId": "0120K000000TO5FQAW"
  },
  "0120K000000TO5KQAW": {
    "available": true,
    "defaultRecordTypeMapping": true,
    "master": false,
    "name": "P2r",
    "recordTypeId": "0120K000000TO5KQAW"
  }
}
```

You can find more info [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.reference_wire_adapters_object_info)

---

Comment: Thanks. Updated my question with the missing line and also mentioned where is the problem. But still, need to know how can I use recordTypeId in @wire

Comment: added in answer. Pls check

Comment: Thanks @salesforce-sas for correcting me and it is working now. Just one confusion on this- JS function can execute in any order. Is 'wire' also following same as the function in terms of execution? if 'yes' then how can we make sure 'wire' getobjectInfo will execute always first?

Comment: In JS, code lines will execute in order. Its same case with `wire` also. However it will have data undefined 1st time but next time when dependent dynamic property changes, it will be invoked again. Refer to https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/272681/use-lwc-wiregetrecord-when-recordid-is-not-always-present/272687#272687

Answer (score 1):

The above code worked for me after declaring recordTypeId

```
   import { LightningElement, wire, api, track } from 'lwc';
   import ORDER_OBJECT from '@salesforce/schema/Order';
   import { getObjectInfo } from 'lightning/uiObjectInfoApi';
   import { getPicklistValues } from 'lightning/uiObjectInfoApi';
   import TYPE_FIELD from '@salesforce/schema/Order.Type';

   export default class Poc extends LightningElement {
   recordTypeId=''
       @wire(getObjectInfo, { objectApiName: ORDER_OBJECT })
       getobjectInfo(result) {
          if (result.data) {
          const rtis = result.data.recordTypeInfos;
        this.recordTypeId = Object.keys(rtis).find((rti) => rtis[rti].name === 'Asia');
    }
}

@wire(getPicklistValues, { recordTypeId: '$recordTypeId', fieldApiName: TYPE_FIELD })
orderTypeOption;
```

}